# Problem with unmarshal response soap request

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb

I have a problem when I try to call another service via a soap request, the logic on the third-party service works correctly but I can't parse the response

`(XmlSubmitResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(url, new ObjectFactory().createSubmitRequest(xmlSubmitRequest))`

```
sms-gateway-server  | Caused by: jakarta.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://mobicon-media.com/schema/sms", local:"SubmitResponse"). Expected elements are (none)
sms-gateway-server  |   at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:693) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3 - ff66b10]
sms-gateway-server  |   at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:230) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3 - ff66b10]
sms-gateway-server  |   at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:225) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3 - ff66b10]
sms-gateway-server  |   at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:92) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3 - ff66b10]
sms-gateway-server  |   at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1102) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3 - ff66b10]
sms-gateway-server  |   at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:527) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3 - ff66b10]
sms-gateway-server  |   at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:509) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3 - ff66b10]
sms-gateway-server  |   at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:49) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3 - ff66b10]
sms-gateway-server  |   at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:137) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3 - ff66b10]
sms-gateway-server  |   at org.glassfish.jaxb.core.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:224) ~[jaxb-core-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3 - ff66b10]
sms-gateway-server  |   at org.glassfish.jaxb.core.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:102) ~[jaxb-core-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3 - ff66b10]
sms-gateway-server  |   at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:330) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3 - ff66b10]
sms-gateway-server  |   at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:313) ~[jaxb-runtime-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3 - ff66b10]
sms-gateway-server  |   at jakarta.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:115) ~[jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar!/:4.0.0]
sms-gateway-server  |   at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:810) ~[spring-oxm-6.0.11.jar!/:6.0.11]
sms-gateway-server  |   ... 41 common frames omitted
sms-gateway-server  |
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://mobicon-media.com/schema/sms" xmlns:ibmSchExtn="http://www.ibm.com/schema/extensions" xmlns:sch="http://mobicon-media.com/schema/sms" xmlns:sms="http://mobicon-media.com/schema/sms" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://mobicon-media.com/schema/sms" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

    <xsd:complexType name="xml_address">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute name="Ton" type="xsd:unsignedByte" use="optional"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="Npi" type="xsd:unsignedByte" use="optional"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="xml_receipt_status">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="DELIVRD"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="EXPIRED"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="DELETED"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="UNDELIV"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="ACCEPTD"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="UNKNOWN"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="REJECTD"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <!-- date format is 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' -->
    <xsd:simpleType name="xml_date_time">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="xml_message_id">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:maxLength value="65"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:complexType name="xml_binary_data">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute default="NONE" name="McDeliveryReceipt" type="sch:xml_mc_delivery_receipt" use="optional"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="xml_text_data">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute default="NONE" name="McDeliveryReceipt" type="sch:xml_mc_delivery_receipt" use="optional"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="xml_wappush_data">
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Caption" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Url">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:pattern value="http://.*"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:all>
        <xsd:attribute default="NONE" name="McDeliveryReceipt" type="sch:xml_mc_delivery_receipt" use="optional"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="xml_delivery_notification">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <!-- The reference id of the message returned in submit response -->
            <xsd:element name="MessageId" nillable="false" type="sch:xml_message_id"/>
            <!-- Submission date and time. -->
            <xsd:element name="SubmitDate" nillable="false" type="sch:xml_date_time"/>
            <!-- Date and time the status has changed, or message delivery time when stat is set to 'DELIVRD'. -->
            <xsd:element name="DoneDate" nillable="false" type="sch:xml_date_time"/>
            <!-- Current status of the message. -->
            <xsd:element name="Status" nillable="false" type="sch:xml_receipt_status"/>
            <!-- Part of the original message text. -->
            <xsd:element name="Text">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="xml_mc_delivery_receipt">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="NONE"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="ALL"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="FAILURE"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="SUCCESS"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:complexType name="xml_data">
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element name="WapPush" type="sch:xml_wappush_data"/>
            <xsd:element name="Binary" type="sch:xml_binary_data"/>
            <xsd:element name="Text" type="sch:xml_text_data"/>
            <xsd:element name="DeliveryNotification" type="sch:xml_delivery_notification"/>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="xml_sar">
        <xsd:attribute name="MsgRefNum" type="xsd:unsignedShort" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="SegmentSeqnum" type="xsd:unsignedByte" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="TotalSegments" type="xsd:unsignedByte" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="xml_channel">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:complexType name="xml_message">
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Muid" type="xsd:long"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Tuid" type="xsd:long"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Sar" type="sch:xml_sar"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ExpireTime" type="sch:xml_date_time"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="ScheduleTime" type="sch:xml_date_time"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="SourcePort" type="xsd:unsignedShort"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="DestinationPort" type="xsd:unsignedShort"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="SourceAddress" type="sch:xml_address"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="DestinationAddress" type="sch:xml_address"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Data" type="sch:xml_data"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Channel" type="sch:xml_channel"/>
        </xsd:all>
        <xsd:attribute name="Login" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="Password" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="xml_submit_status">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="ACCEPTED"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="INVALID_DATA"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="QUEUE_FULL"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="THROTTLED"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="NO_SERVICE"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <!--
        REQUESTS / RESPONSES
    -->

    <xsd:complexType name="xml_submit_request">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Message" type="sch:xml_message"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="xml_submit_response" xmlns:sch="http://mobicon-media.com/schema/sms">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <!-- The reference id of the message, may be used in delivery notifications  -->
            <xsd:element name="MessageId" type="sch:xml_message_id"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="Status" type="sch:xml_submit_status" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="xml_echo_request">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Message" type="sch:xml_message"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="xml_echo_response">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Message" type="sch:xml_message"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element ibmSchExtn:docRoot="true" name="SubmitRequest" type="sch:xml_submit_request"/>
    <xsd:element ibmSchExtn:docRoot="true" name="SubmitResponse" type="sch:xml_submit_response"/>
    <xsd:element ibmSchExtn:docRoot="true" name="EchoRequest" type="sch:xml_echo_request"/>
    <xsd:element ibmSchExtn:docRoot="true" name="EchoResponse" type="sch:xml_echo_response"/>

</xsd:schema>
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "xml_submit_response",
    propOrder = {"messageId"}
)
public class XmlSubmitResponse {
    @XmlElement(
        name = "MessageId",
        required = true
    )
    protected String messageId;
    @XmlAttribute(
        name = "Status",
        required = true
    )
    protected XmlSubmitStatus status;

    public XmlSubmitResponse() {
    }

    public String getMessageId() {
        return this.messageId;
    }

    public void setMessageId(String value) {
        this.messageId = value;
    }

    public XmlSubmitStatus getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(XmlSubmitStatus value) {
        this.status = value;
    }
}
```

In fact, I don't even need the response body, I need to know if the request was successful or not. Mb does anyone have an idea how to fix this or just send a request without trying to deserialize it. If additional data is needed, I can provide it since I am a beginner and do not know what is important))

EDIT

```
@Configuration
public class SoapClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
//        marshaller.setContextPath("by.iba.bb.sms.provider.soap.sms");
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(by.iba.bb.sms.provider.soap.mobicon.XmlSubmitRequest.class);
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller unmarshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
//        marshaller.setContextPath("by.iba.bb.sms.provider.soap.sms");
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(by.iba.bb.sms.provider.soap.mobicon.XmlSubmitResponse.class);
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() {
        WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
        webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller());
        webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(unmarshaller());
        return webServiceTemplate;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you share how you create your `WebServiceTemplate` bean ?

Comment: Yes, I added it to the question

Comment: To determine success check the status for 200 OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've seen, your Class representing the response is not annotated with `jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement`.

Unmarshalling classes without that annotation can be quite touchy sometimes so I'd suggest you to change your unmarshaller with the following code :

```java
    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller unmarshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(by.iba.bb.sms.provider.soap.mobicon.XmlSubmitResponse.class);
        // set CheckForXmlRootElement to false
        marshaller.setCheckForXmlRootElement(false);
        return marshaller;
    }
```

Extract of javadoc of the following method :
`org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.setCheckForXmlRootElement(boolean)`

> Specify whether the `supports(Class)` should check for `@XmlRootElement` annotations.
>
> Default is true, meaning that `supports(Class)` will check for this annotation. However, some JAXB implementations (i.e. EclipseLink MOXy) allow for defining the bindings in an external definition file, thus keeping the classes annotations free. Setting this property to false supports these JAXB implementations.

Could you give it a try and tell me if it works ?

If still not, you could set the `mappedClass` property of the `unmarshaller` to your XML response type `by.iba.bb.sms.provider.soap.mobicon.XmlSubmitResponse.class`.